# C# compiled in mono - Detect OS

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I am trying to get a C# app running under OSX which is not exactly pain free. To work around some of the issues in the short term, I am thinking of setting up some specific rules when it is running in OSX.

But... What can I use to determine whether the app is running under Windows or OSX?

Comment: I have to make sure you understand the following.  You do understand if you use Mono, your application will only work on an operating system with Mono installed, this includes Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound: Really? I thought the CIL outputted by Mono is the same as MS.net2.0. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. I know very little about Mono.

Comment: @spender -- There are some caveats when developing for the Mono runtime. Most have workarounds, though. There's also a migration analyzer for migrating .NET projects: http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA. Long live the Mono.

Comment: @Ramhound: Application will run usually run on Windows without Mono (unless you happen to use a Mono-specific features of course - which isn't common at all).

Comment: @Ramhound: Mono is not required for Windows in this case at least. I am not developing in Mono, I am using Visual Studio. Then I use mono in OSX in order to run the executable which works fine. Had an issue with multi-threading though. Will try to solve it directly in VS next week.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the Mono [wiki](http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Detecting_the_execution_platform) (in my experience, OSX is identified as Unix):

```
int p = (int) Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
if ((p == 4) || (p == 128)) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Running on Unix");
} else {
        Console.WriteLine ("NOT running on Unix");
}
```

**Or**

```
string msg1 = "This is a Windows operating system.";
string msg2 = "This is a Unix operating system.";
string msg3 = "ERROR: This platform identifier is invalid.";

OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
PlatformID     pid = os.Platform;
switch (pid) 
{
    case PlatformID.Win32NT:
    case PlatformID.Win32S:
    case PlatformID.Win32Windows:
    case PlatformID.WinCE:
        Console.WriteLine(msg1);
        break;
    case PlatformID.Unix:
        Console.WriteLine(msg2);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine(msg3);
        break;
}
```

Comment: This will still not tell the difference between linux and OSX.

Comment: Actually, the newer mono has [OSX in the platforms enum](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3ASystem.PlatformID). So depending on the mono version you'll get Unix or MacOSX

Comment: @IanNorton while it HAS the enum, it will never return OSX.

Comment: @IanNorton, you could read the output of ``uname`` (i.e. create a new Process) when the ``PlatformID`` is ``Unix`` - if it says ``Darwin``, it's OS X, anything else should say ``Linux``. (I understand your post was from 4 years ago, but I figured it might  be of use to someone)

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question but this worked for me:

```
//using System.IO
public static string GetOS(){
    if (Directory.Exists("C:\\Windows")) {return "Windows";}
    if (Directory.Exists("/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app")) {return "macOS";}
    return "Linux";
}
```

Comment: brief in the code what worked well for you (with some working solution).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).