# Does C# (Mono) have platform specific macros

Tags: c#, linux, windows, mono

I am developing cross-platform application using C# in Mono. In one class, I have to include platform-specific code. So, the question is: does Mono have platform specific macros like **#if __WINDOWS** or something like that?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329043/how-can-i-conditionally-compile-my-c-sharp-for-mono-vs-microsoft-net/329072#329072 but they are not macro's, just symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this question is about detecting runtime (Mono or .NET) rather than operating system itself

Comment: How about this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9129523/4021938)

Comment: Could use this instead of macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use **Environment.OSVersion** instead of macros.